# Wifi keeps disconnecting in some interval - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager

I have searched about these kind of questions but nothing helped me. Wifi disconnecting in some interval. And the interesting one is when disconnecting happens, I open wifi settings (shows my wifi and other nearby wifis) and it suprisingly reconnects again. It is like quick connecting after fail, if I don't do this, it takes time to reconnect again by itself. Here is some part of a log file and there are two warnings, I don't know how to solve them

```
Yan 13 16:24:38 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540678.7041] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib>
Yan 13 16:24:38 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540678.7042] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Yan 13 16:24:38 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540678.7042] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Yan 13 16:24:38 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: *<warn>*  [1610540678.9569] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doe>
Yan 13 16:24:39 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540679.6601] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Yan 13 16:24:39 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540679.6605] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/N>
Yan 13 16:24:39 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540679.6619] manager: (eno1): new Ethernet device (/org/freedeskto>
Yan 13 16:24:39 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540679.7166] device (eno1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable>
Yan 13 16:24:40 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540680.0557] device (wlp7s0b1): driver supports Access Point (AP) >
Yan 13 16:24:40 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540680.0562] manager: (wlp7s0b1): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/fr>
Yan 13 16:24:40 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540680.0573] device (wlp7s0b1): state change: unmanaged -> unavail>
Yan 13 16:24:40 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: *<warn>*  [1610540680.5458] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Yan 13 16:24:40 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540680.5863] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Yan 13 16:24:40 ramil-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC NetworkManager[915]: <info>  [1610540680.5871] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your motherboard firmware is current. If it isn't, update it. You may be able to use a DOS-bootable USB key to do this.

I can't give specific instructions on how to check, as you have not specified the exact model of your laptop.

Generic steps are something like:

1. Go into the firmware and look for the version, *or* try the `dmidecode` command to check.
2. Go to the manufacturer's website. Look up your exact model.
3. Look for downloads and then BIOS/UEFI updates.
4. Look for the latest version. Compare to what you have installed. If it's newer, download it and look for installation instructions. It is possible that you might need to use Windows for this.